# ¿Cómo enviar formulario con archivos con jQuery, AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario para que la persona con los permisos correspondientes pueda subir un programa de formación y sus aprendices (que son muchísimos). Entonces, para que no sea tan difícil y engorroso, tengo un formulario en el que se ingresan los datos y se sube un archivo excel para que lea sus campos.

El problema es que no me coge los datos del formulario, ni me los envía.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#subirProgramaFormacion", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  console.log("Aquí sí funciona.");


  //Casuantes del presunto error.
  var form = $('#subirInfoFicha')[0];
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  //Estas dos líneas son las que no permiten seguir... Presuntamente.

  console.log("Las 2 líneas anteriores, no me permiten seguir.")

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    url: "recursos/subirFicha.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false

    success: function(data) {

      alert(data);

    },
    error: function() {

      alert("Error.");

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="subirInfoFicha" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario-centrado" method="POST">

  <input type="hidden" name="documento_usuario" value="<?php echo $_POST['documento_usuario']; ?>">

  <div class="input-group">

    <div class="fila-input">

      <input type="number" name="ficha_programa" class="input ficha" max="7" placeholder="Ficha..." required autocomplete="off"> &nbsp;-&nbsp;

      <select name="nivel_programa">

        <option value="" class="place-select">Nivel</option>

        <?php

     $nivel = new nivelesFormacion();
     $nivel->consultarNiveles($mysqli);

     ?>

      </select>

      &nbsp;en&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <input type="text" class="input nombre_programa" name="nombre_programa" placeholder="Nombre de la titulada..." required autocomplete="off">

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <label><span>Fecha inicio lectiva:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" required></label>

      <div class="input-derecha">

        <label><span>Fecha finalización lectiva:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="fecha_finLectiva" name="fecha_finLectiva" required></label>

      </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <label><span>Subir lista de aprendices:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="listaAprendices"></label>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <button type="reset">Rehacer</button>

      <button type="button" class="submit" id="subirProgramaFormacion">Subir programa de formación</button>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

En las 2 líneas que resalté del js, son las que he hecho pruebas y llegué a la conclusión que son las que no permiten que el resto del script se haga. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para enviar todo el formulario, junto con el archivo (que va a ser excel) para que pueda cumplir con los objetivos? Agradezco toda la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregarlo de una forma distinta, como te lo muestro a continuación:
(**Quite el parámetro type de $.ajax y solo deje el method**)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#subirProgramaFormacion").on('click', function () {

        var form_data = new FormData();
        var file_data = $("#file").prop("files")[0];

        form_data.append("file", file_data);
        form_data.append("documento_usuario", $("#documento_usuario").val());
        form_data.append("ficha_programa", $("#ficha_programa").val());
        form_data.append("nivel_programa", $("#nivel_programa").val());
        form_data.append("nombre_programa", $("#nombre_programa").val());
        form_data.append("fecha_inicio", $("#fecha_inicio").val());
        form_data.append("fecha_finLectiva", $("#fecha_finLectiva").val());

        for (var value of form_data.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        $.ajax({

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: form_data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            method: "POST",
            url: "recursos/subirFicha.php",
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

A tu input de tipo FILE le agregué un ID para seleccionarlo desde el JS

En este caso, estoy tomando en cuenta que tu archivo .php se va a encargar de toda la información de tus campos.

Cada input que contenga información va a agregarse como un objeto y se va a concatenar.

Si lo quisieras recuperar en php sería:

```
<?php
        $tmpfilesize = isset($_FILES["file"]["size"]) ? $_FILES["file"]["size"] : 0;
        $tmpfilename = isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) ? $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] : 0;
        $tmpfiletype = isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]) ? $_FILES["file"]["type"] : 0;

        $var1 = $_POST['documento_usuario'];
        $var2 = $_POST['nombre_programa'];
    //... resto del proceso
```

En la parte de html le hice las siguientes correcciones. (**Agregue el ID  a tu input hidden y quite el** )

```
<input type="hidden" id="documento_usuario" name="documento_usuario" value="1">

<div class="input-group">

    <div class="fila-input">

        <input type="number" name="ficha_programa" id="ficha_programa" class="input ficha" max="7" placeholder="Ficha..." required autocomplete="off"> &nbsp;-&nbsp;

        <select name="nivel_programa" id="nivel_programa">

            <option value="" class="place-select">Nivel</option>
        </select>

        &nbsp;en&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <input type="text" class="input nombre_programa" name="nombre_programa" id="nombre_programa" placeholder="Nombre de la titulada..." required autocomplete="off">

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

        <label><span>Fecha inicio lectiva:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" required></label>

        <div class="input-derecha">

            <label><span>Fecha finalización lectiva:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="fecha_finLectiva" name="fecha_finLectiva" required></label>

        </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

        <label><span>Subir lista de aprendices:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="listaAprendices" id="file"></label>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

        <button type="reset">Rehacer</button>

        <button type="button" class="submit" id="subirProgramaFormacion">Subir programa de formación</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

Esto me ha funcionado bien, probablemente tienes un error al querer seleccionar el elemento de tu form.

Comment: Tal parece que ya lo lee. Me pone en un alter el [object FormData], peeero... No me lo envía ahora. No me envía los datos.

Comment: Puedes hacer un `var_dump($_FILES); var_dump($_POST); ` Y desde consola puedes verificar que se esta mandando por POST hacía tu php cuando haces tu petición. Además puedes revisar que datos se están mandando en la variable form_data `console.log(form_data);`

Comment: No. Es que ni siquiera me funciona. Lo que va dentro del success: function(), no se ejecuta.

Comment: Me refiero a que pongas un `console.log(form_data);` antes de que se mande el `$.ajax`, para que cuando le des click en el botón te muestre en consola los valores, en este momento omite el $.ajax. Además en tu HTML quita lo que tienes de `<form id="subirInfoFicha" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario-centrado" method="POST">`

Comment: Realiza por pasos estos procesos.
- Muestra en consola los valores que tiene el form_data, (**Antes de que se envíen por Ajax**)
`for (var value of form_data.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }`
**Ocupa este for para ver los valores de tu FormData, una disculpa con el console.log, no se muestran, mas bien se tienen que mostrar de esta forma**
- Revisa en el navegador que ocupes, la petición y los valores que se están enviando vía POST

Comment: ¿Por qué debería eliminar el formulario? Y ya hice lo del for. Me aparecen una variable que la toma como indefinida.SIn embargo, lo que es la primera fila (donde está el número de ficha, el nivel y el programa e formación) no me los toma. El archivo sí.

Comment: Cuando envío los datos sólo con un {method: "POST", url: "recursos/subirFicha.php"} sí llega a la página.

Comment: He actualizado el código. Eso es lo que he hecho de cambios. El console.log() dentro de la función del succes no se ejecuta.

Comment: No es necesario que tengas tu `<form>` ya que el que esta detectando el evento del **clic es el jquery**. El `<form>` lo ocupas cuando tienes un botón de tipo submit y es el que hace tu proceso de enviar tu información a tu servidor, ya que los parámetros del `<form>` sustituyen la parte de javascript.

Comment: El detalle que comentas sobre la variable indefinida, (una disculpa, omití ese campo), es porque falta agregar el **id** a tu `<input type="hidden" id="documento_usuario" name="documento_usuario" value="1">`. En este caso, ya no te debería de aparecer indefinida esa variable.

Aquí recuerda que estamos concatenando en base a **ID** 

`form_data.append("documento_usuario", $("#documento_usuario").val());`

Comment: Aquí detecte un error mío, debes de quitar el parámetro **type** de tu `$.ajax` y solo tener tu parámetro **method**, con esto te debería de funcionar a la perfección. 

Hice la prueba, tomando en cuenta las observaciones que te hice en los comentarios pasados.

Comment: Ya lo he podido resolver. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pues el único error que noto, es que falta la coma después de:

```
processData: false,
```

Ya con eso debe de funcionar el llamado.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#subirProgramaFormacion", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  console.log("Aquí sí funciona.");


  //Casuantes del presunto error.
  var form = $('#subirInfoFicha')[0];
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  //Estas dos líneas son las que no permiten seguir... Presuntamente.


 console.log($('#subirInfoFicha')[0]);

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    url: "recursos/subirFicha.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: function(data) {

      alert(data);

    },
    error: function() {

      alert("Error.");

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="subirInfoFicha" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario-centrado" method="POST">

  <input type="hidden" name="documento_usuario" value=""/>

  <div class="input-group">

    <div class="fila-input">

      <input type="number" name="ficha_programa" class="input ficha" max="7" placeholder="Ficha..." required autocomplete="off"/>

      <select name="nivel_programa">

        <option value="" class="place-select">Nivel</option>

      </select>

      <input type="text" class="input nombre_programa" name="nombre_programa" placeholder="Nombre de la titulada..." required autocomplete="off"/>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <label><span>Fecha inicio lectiva:</span>;
                <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" required/>
            </label>

      <div class="input-derecha">

        <label><span>Fecha finalización lectiva:</span>;
                    <input type="date" id="fecha_finLectiva" name="fecha_finLectiva" required/>
                </label>

      </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <label><span>Subir lista de aprendices:</span>
                <input type="file" name="listaAprendices"/>
            </label>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="fila-input">

      <button type="reset">Rehacer</button>

      <button type="button" class="submit" id="subirProgramaFormacion">Subir programa de formación</button>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente manera :

```js
var file_data = $('#subirInfoFicha').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
//para agregar parametros extras al formData
    form_data.append('accion', "subirArchivo");
    form_data.append('cliente', $('#txtCliente').val());
    $.ajax({
             url: 'recursos/subirFicha.php',
             dataType: 'JSON',//cambia tu respuesta a la que uses
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             data: form_data,
             type: 'POST'
             }).done((res)=>{
             console.log(res)
             })
```

**Ediccion:** a tu `<input type="file"` le falta el id en este método que uso creo un nuevo form data y obtengo los valores de todos los input prueba hacerlo de esta forma.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si bien ya has marcado la respuesta como correcta, me gustaria hacerte una recomendacion:

1.- Por que agregarle el evento click al boton, cuando podrias agregar el evento submit a tu formulario ejemplo:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#subirInfoFicha", function(e) {}
```

2.- En la data que vas a mandar la información, mandas todo el formulario al que le estas haciendo `submit`  Ejemplo:

```
data: new FormData(this),
```

3.- Esto mandará todo el formulario, incluyendo el archivo.